# Is this a rare character encoding for Czech?

Tags: character-encoding

I recently downloaded gigabytes of data (text) in multiple files that I want to automatically process. However, the charset or actual encoding of text is wrong. The problem is that text editors such as Notepad++, SublimeText 3 or Word detect it simply as ANSI. I've tried all charsets there were available, but there are still parts that are amiss across files.

**Default ANSI encoding (wrong special characters):**

> OBJEVUJE SE ZELENÁ KNÍ®KA
>
> Frantík Severýn sedí na prázdných bednách od cukru, pohupuje bosýma
> nohama a naslouchá kázání páně Bočanovu. Kázání nepatří jemu, nýbrľ
> paní Bílkové, která stojí před pultem. Frantík se tváří, jako by se
> nezajímal o nic jiného neľ o své zablácené klátící se nohy. Zatím vąak
> napíná uąi, aby mu neuąlo ani slovíčko.
>
> »Tak to dál nepůjde, milá paní,« křičí hokynář a jeho tlustý zátylek
> je rudý zlostí. »Jedno zboľí nezaplatíte a uľ zas chcete nové na dluh.
> Copak si myslíte, ľe kradu?«

**ISO 8859-2 encoding (wrong quotation marks):**

> OBJEVUJE SE ZELENÁ KNÍŽKA
>
> Frantík Severýn sedí na prázdných bednách od cukru, pohupuje bosýma
> nohama a naslouchá kázání páně Bočanovu. Kázání nepatří jemu, nýbrž
> paní Bílkové, která stojí před pultem. Frantík se tváří, jako by se
> nezajímal o nic jiného než o své zablácené klátící se nohy. Zatím však
> napíná uši, aby mu neušlo ani slovíčko.
>
> ťTak to dál nepůjde, milá paní,Ť křičí hokynář a jeho tlustý zátylek
> je rudý zlostí. ťJedno zboží nezaplatíte a už zas chcete nové na dluh.
> Copak si myslíte, že kradu?Ť

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

> OBJEVUJE SE ZELENÁ KNÍŽKA
>
> Frantík Severýn sedí na prázdných bednách od cukru, pohupuje bosýma
> nohama a naslouchá kázání páně Bočanovu. Kázání nepatří jemu, nýbrž
> paní Bílkové, která stojí před pultem. Frantík se tváří, jako by se
> nezajímal o nic jiného než o své zablácené klátící se nohy. Zatím však
> napíná uši, aby mu neušlo ani slovíčko.
>
> »Tak to dál nepůjde, milá paní,« křičí hokynář a jeho tlustý zátylek
> je rudý zlostí. »Jedno zboží nezaplatíte a už zas chcete nové na dluh.
> Copak si myslíte, že kradu?«

**What character encoding is this?**

After reading [this](http://luki.sdf-eu.org/txt/cs-encodings-faq.html) I suspect that it might be an older/legacy one, but I am not sure how to fix it as I don't know any software that supports it. Another option is that it might be just corrupt, because all quotation marks seem to be encoded as ť/Ť. How can I verify this?

EDIT: hex information:

```
KNÍ®KA = 4B 4E CD AE 4B 41
»Tak to dál nepůjde = BB 54 61 6B 20 74 6F 20 64 E1 6C 20 6E 65 70 F9 6A 64 65
co má chu» vstát = 63 6F 20 6D E1 20 63 68 75 BB 20 76 73 74 E1 74
```

Comment: You recently downloaded gigabytes of data. Is it business related, or academic related? Depending on the situation, the first step might be to ask the people who are maintaining or created the files in the original. Then try some specialists in forums specific to the language. Here's pretty multinational.

Comment: @KrassiEm these are regular books in txt format, mostly sf and fantasy, which I want to analyze statistically. The source of data is one pretty difficult to contact, unfortunately…

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with the language. It will take a few days to get to the solution. One thing to do is try to get some parser to verify the correctness of spelling. Then you can sort out the problematic ones. However please be careful what you are doing with the books. There may be copyrights to some of them. Science fiction is not that old stuff.

Comment: @KrassiEm thanks, will keep this in mind, although derived works for scientific purposes are generally good to go :)

Comment: If you are working on  Linux, maybe you can formulate the correct patterns for sed, the stream editor to perform the corrections? I will be quite curious to hear other people who are more knowledgeable about the matter.

Comment: Unfortunately win noob here :(

Comment: Actually I read the question again "Is this a rare character encoding for Czech" and it sounds like a good idea to ask someone who is a linguist and knows very well Czech. They could be helpful with an advice on what to do next.

Comment: I am a linguist and I speak Czech, but I still can't identify this one :\

Comment: If the download was as text and via HTTP, the Content-Type header oh s a common way of communicating the character encoding.

Comment: @TomBlodget zipped package, unfortunately. I think I will need to write a program to cycle through all possible encodings…

Answer (score 0):

Use UTF-8, not ascii, not iso-..., not latin....

latin1 comes close, but misses the `ř`.

You say it was "downloaded".  Can you show us the hex for the characters in question?

`»Žřč` converts to hex:
`C2BB C5BD C599 C48D` in UTF-8 -- the only one that can handle all chars
`BB 8E 3F 3F` in latin1
`BB 8E F8 3F` in cp1250
`3F AE F8 E8` in latin2
Note:  3F is `?`, meaning conversion problems.

Hex `BB` is `ť` in latin2.

Comment: Provided HEX info. It seems that **ť** and **»** are encoded exactly the same way, as BB—does that mean the information has been lost? I read on the DL page that converting that file with Calibre on Czech Windows fixed the issue, but it didn't work for me on my Polish one, and I don't know how credible the source was.

Comment: If I read http://czech.typeit.org/ correctly (not that it is a definitive resource), the "quotes" in Czech are `„““”`, not `»«`.  So, if you need the angle quotes and the accented `ť`, you cannot get _both_ without going to utf8.  I don't see `ť` in the text in question, so is there really a problem?

Comment: "co má chu» vstát" ← this should be a `ť`, not `«`. Quotes I can fix, but distinguishing quotes from actual `ť` might be a bit tricky atm…

Comment: If the input file has hex `BB`, I don't see how to fix it.  How are you dumping the hex?

Comment: In your link, how is `ť` represented?  Perhaps as `t'`?  I don't see that.  Also, note how old the document it.  It mentions Unicode 2.00, which may be a decade old.

Comment: Depending on encoding, it displays ť correctly and ť instead of quotes, or quotes correctly and quote close instead of ť. I suspect the document is about 5-12 years old.

Comment: Character set issues are a challenge in MySQL.  I have been tackling them for a decade.  Still, new puzzles (such as yours) crop up.

Comment: Well, I guess it's RegEx-ing time… Thanks for the input nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852

At least it looks like it has all required characters